# HTML-Graphs LIB for Python doesn't work

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm an Ubuntu user and I've tried to make use of HTML-Graphs source code, that I need for my python script (well... it's not library but source code, I guess? If I needed anything for my scripts, I was just installing libraries through Ubuntu Softwate Center or pip command). Please, check HTML-Graphs here: http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/pygraphs/index.php?page=download. So my problem is: I download it as zip file... and then what? I tried to do comments like 'python graphs.py' in hope to "install it" (sorry, lack of words) but it didn't work out. What should I do to properly use the instructions from the HTML-Graphs source code? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the file `graphs.py` to your current project directory and then use it in your scripts with `import graphs`